# Regex: take everything after match

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have many strings in a dataframe, an example being:

```
adrianos ristorante 2930 beverly glen circle los angeles 310475 9807 italian
```

I want to take all words/characters after the phone number. I have the regex for getting the phone number and space after(`([0-9]{6}\s[0-9]{4})\s`). What I want is all characters after this. In this case it's `italian`but it could be something like `asian fusion` or `indian and thai`.

Comment: Try `[0-9]{6}\s[0-9]{4}\s+(.+)`. Is it a Pandas df?

Comment: Yes, I'm using pandas

Comment: Say if I want to extract the restaurant name I could use `^(\w+\s?\w+?)\s[0-9]+`. How would I scale this to n words in restaurant name? i.e. `arnie mortons of chicago 435 s la cienega blvd los angeles 310246 1501 american`

Comment: You can probably use a simple `.*?` pattern, [`^(.*?)\s+[0-9]+`](https://regex101.com/r/dN4qav/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Pandas, you may use

```
[0-9]{6}\s[0-9]{4}\s+(.+)
                    ^^^^^
```

The code will look like

```
df['col'].str.extract('[0-9]{6}\s[0-9]{4}\s+(.+)')
```

Note you should wrap the part you need to extract with a capturing group, `(...)`. See [Pandas reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

> **pat** : *string*
>
> Regular expression pattern with capturing groups

Answer (score 0):

You can do (in Notepad++):

Find What: (.*)([0-9]{6}\s[0-9]{4})\s(.*)
Replace with: $3

$3 gives the 3rd argument which is everything after your matching phone number.

Answer (score 0):

Using this regular expression:
`/([0-9]{6}\s[0-9]{4})\s(.*$)/m`

You will have anything after the phone number, until the end of the line (you can omit the `m` flag if you want to get everything until the end of the string), in the second capture group.

Answer (score 0):

You can use positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=[0-9]{6}\s[0-9]{4}\s).*
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/09grud/1).

Comment: This throws the following error in pandas: `pattern contains no capture groups`